# Kibana query regex not working

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I used zone field as a string and that's values are **ap-south-1a, ap-south-1b, ap-south-12,ap-south-123,ap-south-1A**.If I queried the ap-south-1, it should return all the ap-south-1 related records.I'm struggling the Kibana regex query.I know my query is wrong because it didn't work.

**Query:**

```
 zone: "/ap-south-1+[a-zA-Z0-9]/"
```

Comment: The `+` should go after the brackets: `ap-south-1[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Comment: @val, I tried this.It didn't work

Comment: also make sure to remove the space after the colon, i.e. `zone:"/ap-south-1[a-zA-Z0-9]+/"`

Comment: I tried that also but I didn't get output

Comment: Oh wait, you need to remove the double quotes `zone:/ap-south-1[a-zA-Z0-9]+/` otherwise the regexp is taken literally and will be used as an exact match

Comment: The zone is a string field so how is it possible to query without double quotes.Anyhow, I tried this but no output.

Comment: String fields don't need to be queried with double quotes. double quotes must be used for exact matches (i.e. when you don't want the input to be analyzed), when using regular expressions you only need to use slashes `/.../`

Comment: Can you share the underlying query that is generated by Kibana?

Comment: I thought you know discover in Kibana.I tried the query in Kibana discover.It showed me no results found.

Comment: In the Discover tab, just above the Time column, there's a small arrow pointing to the top, click it and you'll see the request being generated. Share that please.

Comment: {
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "zone:/ap-south-1[a-zA-Z0-9]+/",
          "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": 1493801405075,
                  "lte": 1494406205075,
                  "format": "epoch_millis"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Are you using an old version of Kibana and ES?

Comment: I checked the Kibana version 4.5

Comment: Can I do prefix value match in the search bar?.I'm not familiar in Kibana.